# Having trouble updating Azure environment with an imported .csv

Tags: powershell, csv, azure-active-directory

Tried running this script to alter in bulk the membership rules to dynamic groups with this script but running into an issue. Here is the script and error:
[image]

Comment: `-MembershipRule` parameter is only available in the Preview Version of this cmdlet. You need to `Install-Module AzureADPreview` first. You should also consider using `Update-MgGroup` instead.

Comment: I installed the module and imported the module then ran the same script but got same error unfortunately. Anything else in mind that could work, I feel like I am very close. Also where would I use Update-MgGroup?

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.groups/update-mggroup?view=graph-powershell-1.0&preserve-view=true and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.groups/get-mggroup?view=graph-powershell-1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch the membership rule of the Group, I used the below command:

```
Get-AzADGroup -Filter "groupTypes/any(c:c eq 'DynamicMembership')" | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq "Dynamic-Group1" } | Select-Object DisplayName, MembershipRule
```

[image]

> **Note** that: You should make use of `Az` module or `Microsoft.Graph` module instead of Azure AD module as suggested by @*Santiago Squarzon* to resolve error.

To update the group membership rules, I modified the script like below:

```
$csvPath = "C:\Users\rukmini\Desktop\dynamicgroups.csv"
$csvData = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath

foreach ($row in $csvData) {
  $DisplayName = $row.DisplayName
  $membershiprule = $row.membershiprule


# Get the group object by display name
$group = Get-AzADGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$DisplayName'"

if ($group) {
    # Update the dynamic membership rule
     Update-AzADGroup -ObjectId $group.Id -MembershipRule $membershipRule
     Write-Host "Updated dynamic membership rule for group: $DisplayName"
} else 
{
     Write-Host "Group $DisplayName not found."
}
}
```

[image]

The **membership rule of the Group** got updated successfully like below:

[image]

**References:**

[Update-AzADGroup (Az.Resources)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/update-azadgroup?view=azps-10.2.0)

[Update-MgGroup (Microsoft.Graph.Groups)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.groups/update-mggroup?view=graph-powershell-1.0&preserve-view=true)

Comment: Thank you- this worked partially as the change was made and no error came but only the last row in my csv is being changed in Azure whereas I have about 30 rows with rules needing to be update. Is there something else needed to be changed so this script is able to bulk change membership rules?

Comment: Can you try putting the logic inside the foreach loop and try

Comment: Sorry I am failing to understand how to put the logic inside the foreach. Where would the bracket go:
foreach  ($row in $csvData) {
  $DisplayName = $row.DisplayName
  $membershiprule = $row.membershiprule
}
$group = Get-AzADGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$DisplayName'"
if ($group) {
    # Update the dynamic membership rule
     Update-AzADGroup -ObjectId $group.Id -MembershipRule $membershipRule
     Write-Host "Updated dynamic membership rule for group: $DisplayName"
} else 
{
     Write-Host "Group $DisplayName not found."
}

Comment: Try closing the foreach bracket in the end of the script

Comment: Thank YOU! I got back results that all my rows were updated instead of just the last one. Here is the final code if it could come to use and help for anyone:
foreach ($row in $csvData) {
  $DisplayName = $row.DisplayName
  $membershiprule = $row.membershiprule
$group = Get-AzADGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$DisplayName'"
if ($group) {
    # Update the dynamic membership rule
     Update-AzADGroup -ObjectId $group.Id -MembershipRule $membershipRule
     Write-Host "Updated dynamic membership rule for group: $DisplayName"
} else 
{     Write-Host "Group $DisplayName not found."
}
}